# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Handle JavaScript Redirects

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

This is how my ingress definition looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 8080
```

When I apply this I get a working ingress. I am able to make a request to:

```
http://kubernetes.docker.internal/myapp
```

The response from my app is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/auth/" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "/auth/"
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    If you are not redirected automatically, follow this <a href='/auth'>link</a>.
</body>

</html>
```

And guess what... The user is redirected to:

```
http://kubernetes.docker.internal/auth/
```

which trows a 404 error. I actually need to be redirected to:

```
http://kubernetes.docker.internal/myapp/auth/
```

In other words, I need to proxy **myapp** and to have that **/myapp** prefix in every URL.

Comment: Can you try with `path` without the wildcard/regex? Also `ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` what are you using this for? Last point - Check inside the physical ingress controllers. You can see the nginx.conf and see exactly how the rewrite is written. Could be something small in your ingress config.

Comment: I don't think this URL `kubernetes.docker.internal ` is working ingress URL

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I am using Docker for Desktop which provides this fancy URL. If my app serves a normal response without redirects it works fine. Maybe I didn't understand what you tried to say, any idea on how to test if it is working ingress URL?

Comment: @Dandy It works the same without the wildcards and a rewrite URL /. I have no idea about ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" I just saw it somewhere. Here is a link to my nginx.conf. https://pastebin.com/BdLhfiUd

Comment: @KaloyanManev I think the issue is in the rewrite itself. You don't need a rewrite. Look at line 522 of that pastebin, it's rewriting anything to `/myapp` to `/` (root). Try removing it. Also, technically, your path should just be `/` because you're appending the `myapp/` in your URL yourself.

Comment: @Dandy If I remove the rewrite and visit kubernetes.docker.internal/myapp/auth/ I am redirected to http://kubernetes.docker.internal/auth/ and my app works but I want the /myapp prefix to stay there.